# Is there a way to implement "onShow" using Prototype JS?

Tags: prototypejs

I searched the Prototype docs but found nothing. Did I miss something, or is there no such thing as onshow? I want to call a function when an element (a div in my case) is made visible. Is there such functionality in the Prototype framework? If not, I need a push in the right direction so I can solve it another way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is an event that is fired when the `.show()` method is called on elements there is not.

But you can test if an element is visible by using the `$('myelementid').visible()` method.

Also a different way I have done it in the past is using the Script.aculo.us `.appear()` method which has a afterFinish callback - for example

```
$('myelementid').appear({'afterFinish':function(effect){
   //the afterFinish callback passes the effect as the first parameter

    //call other function with element
    otherfunction(effect.element);
});
```

technically you would only need to load the `effects.js` file of Script.aculo.us instead of all of the library to get the core effects methods.